# Find all instances of a date in a date range - SQL Server

Tags: date, sql-server-2017

I need to find the price for an item for each financial year end date in a date range. In this case the financial year is e.g. 31 March

The table I have for example:

| ItemID | Value | DateFrom | DateTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | '2019/01/01' | '2021/02/28' |
| 1 | 11 | '2021/03/01' | '2021/05/01' |

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/86151f)

The SQL would thus result in the above table to be:

| ItemID | Value | DateFrom | DateTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | '2019/01/01' | '2019/03/30' |
| 1 | 10 | **'2020/03/31'** | '2021/02/28' |
| 1 | 11 | '2020/03/01' | '2021/03/30' |
| 1 | 11 | **'2020/03/31'** | '2021/05/01' |

Comment: What have you tried, show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it, but a prerequisite is the creation of a `table` called **financial_years** and filling it with data. This would be the structure of the table:

**financial_years(id, DateFrom, DateTo)**

Now that you have this table, you can do something like this:

```
select ItemID, Value, financial_years.DateFrom, financial_years.DateTo
from items
join financial_years
on (items.DateFrom between financial_years.DateFrom and financial_years.DateTo) or
   (items.DateTo between financial_years.DateFrom and financial_years.DateTo)
order by financial_years.DateFrom;
```

Answer (score 1):

**The accepted answer is not correct, as it does not split out different parts of the year which have different `value`s.**

You also do not *need* a `Year` table, although it can be beneficial. You can generate it on the fly using a `VALUES` table.

Note also a better way to check the intervals overlap, using `AND` not `OR`

```sql
WITH Years AS (
    SELECT
        YearStart = DATEFROMPARTS(v.yr, 3, 31),
        YearEnd = DATEFROMPARTS(v.yr + 1, 3, 31)
    FROM (VALUES
      (2015),(2016),(2017),(2018),(2019),(2020),(2021),(2022),(2023),(2024),(2025),(2026),(2027),(2028),(2029),(2030),(2031),(2032),(2033),(2034),(2035),(2036),(2037),(2038),(2039)
    ) v(yr)
)
SELECT
    i.ItemID,
    i.Value,
    DateFrom = CASE WHEN i.DateFrom > y.YearStart THEN i.DateFrom ELSE y.YearStart END,
    DateTo =   CASE WHEN i.DateTo > y.YearEnd THEN y.YearEnd ELSE i.DateTo END
FROM items i
JOIN Years y ON i.DateFrom <= y.YearEnd
             AND i.DateTo >= y.YearStart;
```